# Splitting Json string into individual strings in Python

Tags: python, json, regex

I am learning to write log parsing script with json and re in python.
Need to read log file, find lines having Json response, parse and print in tabular form.
I want grab each of the substring using finditer, but my code is matching entire concatenated string.

```
Code:
for m in re.finditer(r'{"APIResponse".*"Type":"\w+"}}',line,re.I):
   print (m.group(0))
```

But the lines having Json strings, are sometimes concatenated in this format:

```
{"APIResponse":{"ResponseCode":0,"ResponseText":"Success"},"TxnResp":{"Type":"internet"}}{"APIResponse":{"ResponseCode":0,"ResponseText":"Success"},"TxnResp":{"Type":"directdebit"}}Pament Request Output from Server ....
{"APIResponse":{"ResponseCode":0,"ResponseText":"Success"},"TxnResp":{"Type":"directdebit"}}{"APIResponse":{"ResponseCode":0,"ResponseText":"Success"},"TxnResp":{"Type":"directdebit"}}2018-07-09 10:01:18 DEBUG PaymentGatewayICSClient:981 - ClientRef         = 1587604390003
{"APIResponse":{"ResponseCode":0,"ResponseText":"Success"},"TxnResp":{"Type":"internet"}}{"APIResponse":{"ResponseCode":0,"ResponseText":"Success"},"TxnResp":{"Type":"internet"}}2018-07-09 10:01:18 DEBUG PaymentGatewayICSClient:981 - ClientRef         = 158760439AX00
{"APIResponse":{"ResponseCode"-1,"ResponseText":"Fail9"},"TxnResp":{"Type":"directdebit"}}{"APIResponse":{"ResponseCode":101,"ResponseText":"Success"},"TxnResp":{"Type":"directdebit"}}Transaction Denied
```

Comment: How are you generating `line`, and what result are you trying to get? Your regex should work for extracting the JSON part of the line.

Comment: I think you just need to add ? . So your regex will look like __{"APIResponse".*?"Type":"\w+"}}__  https://regex101.com/r/IqS1fq/1

Answer (score 0):

Your current regular expression is a greedy regex, which means it tries to match as long a string as it can; if line is

```
{"APIResponse":{"ResponseCode":0,"ResponseText":"Success"},"TxnResp":{"Type":"internet"}}{"APIResponse":{"ResponseCode":0,"ResponseText":"Success"},"TxnResp":{"Type":"directdebit"}}Pament Request Output from Server ....
```

running

```
for m in re.finditer(r'{"APIResponse".*"Type":"\w+"}}',line,re.I):
   print (m.group(0))
```

will give the result

```
{"APIResponse":{"ResponseCode":0,"ResponseText":"Success"},"TxnResp":{"Type":"internet"}}{"APIResponse":{"ResponseCode":0,"ResponseText":"Success"},"TxnResp":{"Type":"directdebit"}}
```

To make the regex act in a lazy manner, so that it returns the shortest string it can, add an `?` after the `.*` characters:

```
for m in re.finditer(r'{"APIResponse".*?"Type":"\w+"}}',line,re.I):
   print (m.group(0))
```

output:

```
{"APIResponse":{"ResponseCode":0,"ResponseText":"Success"},"TxnResp":{"Type":"internet"}}
{"APIResponse":{"ResponseCode":0,"ResponseText":"Success"},"TxnResp":{"Type":"directdebit"}}
```

[Regular-expressions.info](http://regular-expressions.info) is an excellent resource for learning more about how regular expressions work.

Comment: I did try this before, but overlooked the output. working fine now. 
And will definitely go through the regex resources you shared.